# Relations between Betti numbers for clique complex

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Given a clique complex $K$ constructed from a discrete set of vertices (i.e. its faces are isomorphic to the set of cliques in the 1-skeleton of $K$.), it seems that the Betti numbers $\beta_k$ defined for the homology of $K$ are in some sense correlated since the $n(0\leq n\leq\dim K)$-simplexes in $K$ are completely determined by the 1-skeleton. Beyond the classical result given by discrete Morse theory

$$-f_{k-1}+f_{k}-f_{k+1}\leq \,\beta_k \, \leq f_k$$

where $f_k$ are the number of $k$-faces in $K$, are there further results concerning the relations between $\beta_k$ and $\beta_{k+1}$ ? Since there exists many upper bounds for the sum of Betti numbers for a given clique complex (e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4775.pdf)), is such bound providing any information about the relations in between any two Betti numbers? Or it is just casual counting bound?

Any comment or reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: The barycentric subdivision of a simplicity complex is always a flag complex and this doesn't change the homology.

Comment: Since you ask "are there further...relations between $\beta_k$ and $\beta_{k+1}$, and since the inequality you are citing holds for *any* simplicial complex (not only for clique complexes of the 1-skeleton), it is not off-topic to mention the usual formula, also valid in general and not specific to your setting, for the Euler-characteristic: $f_0-f_1+\dotsm+(-1)^{\mathrm{dim}(K)} f_{\mathrm{dim}(K)} = \beta_0 - \beta_1 + \dotsm + (-1)^{\mathrm{dim}(K)}\beta_{\mathrm{dim}(K)}$. Again, this is a validity on the class of *all* abstract simplicial complexes, not *specific* to your question.

Comment: @PeterHeinig Thanks! Sure, but for a more general simplicial complex I am not even sure in that case if two consecutive Betti numbers are related since there could be much more possibilities than a clique complex.